# ActiveAdmin and handling a subset of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We use ActiveAdmin and have a notion of an event at like http://domain.com/admin/events/3/edit. I'd like to be able to edit the finance data aspect of this (something like http://domain.com/admin/events/3/finance/edit or http://domain.com/admin/events/3/edit/finance). How would you organize it? I was thinking of trying to do a custom controller like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event, as: 'Finance'  do
  permit_params %i(venue_id name event_type_id)

  before_create do |event|
    event.created_by = current_user
  end

  show do |event|
    panel 'Details' do
      attributes_table_for event do
        row :id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but this doesn't seem to work. What would be the most basic pattern to have a controller which has a portion of our data and can work well within ActiveAdmin?

Comment: Finance data? “Portion of our data”? What are you asking?

Comment: what would be the preferred pattern. A member_action? A different controller? First time using ActiveAdmin and just trying to figure out what the best pattern is for displaying more information that could be edited.

Comment: I can't answer that question because I don't understand what you're asking. Where is this “finance data” coming from and what relation does it have to `Event`?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking about nesting a resource inside another, see 'Belongs To' on [this page](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html)